# Giving password on propmt while SSH using java

Tags: java

I am able to run commands on remote machine using java jsch library.
Scenario is when I am executing a particular command from putty it is prompting for password and a reason to execute this command(for some security purpose).
Now I want to do the same executing that command and passing password and reason on propmt using java program only.

How can I achieve this?

"There is nothing code specific actually. I am executing a pbrun command in unix using putty with command "/opt/bin/pbrun username". which on entering prompt me for password and reason to login. As I am accessing it thorough putty I am able to pass values. I want to pass those value using java program."

Comment: You need to show us what you are doing, *in code*, for us to answer questions like this: you're asking for a very broad response with any number of implementations. What have you tried?

Comment: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html shows how to sudo and sudo means type a password.

Comment: There is nothing code specific actually. I am executing a pbrun command in unix using putty with command "/opt/bin/pbrun username". which on entering prompt me for password and reason to login. As I am accessing it thorough putty I am able to pass values. I want to pass those value using java program.

Answer (score 0):

Basically **you cannot do that this way**, SSH does not permit to pipe the password because of security reasons.

**However, what you can do is** (*roughly*) to generate a public/private keypair with `ssh-keygen` and place it to the host's `.ssh/authorized_keys`. **Then you can SSH without a password**, that is my usual solution for the problem (however, I'd love to hear any alternatives). There are plenty of tutorials on the topic, simply search for the ["passwordless ssh"](https://www.google.com/search?q=passwordless%20ssh) expressions.

It may sound trivial, but believe me, you will spend hours on configuring it :-). The `ssh -x` will be your friend (for one you'll need *exact* privileges on the key files and stuff like that).